# Present Perfect or Past Perfect in a conditional sentence. What makes more sense?

Tags: sentence-construction, conditional-constructions, conditionals

1. If you hadn't ever fallen out of the sky, I don't know what I would
   do now.
2. If you haven't ever fallen out of the sky, I don't know what I would
   do now.
3. If you never fell out of the sky, I don't know what I would do now.
4. If you wouldn't have fallen out of the sky, I don't know what I
   would do now.

I really want to know which version is considered the only grammatically correct by prescriptivists and which are used in everyday life.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a *very* odd thing to say in everyday life, but (1) is the best way to express what I assume your meaning is.

(2) *If you haven't ever [done this], you should try it some time - you might enjoy it.*

(3) [If you never did you should](https://www.urbo.com/content/dr-seuss-quotes-to-live-by/).

(4) doesn't make sense to me in any context.

Comment: I thought as much. It's the same pattern as in "If you hadn't eaten that hot dog, you would be well now." But you did eat it, so now you're at (the) hospital.
As for (4) like it or not, many people say that. For example, "If I wouldn't have come home early, she would have freaked out" instead of "If I hadn't come home early...", or "I wish I would have known" instead of "I wish I had known".